# REGEXP_EXTRACT specific string to extract year or month in Google Data Studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm trying to categorize my sites but they have not always the same uri-structure so I want to extract the year in one column and in the second one I want to extract the month.

The results should be year and months in seperate columns/fields:

| url | year | months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /www.site.com/path1/resort/2021/02/sitename | 2021 | 02 |
| /www.site.com/path1/2021/02 | 2021 | 02 |
| /www.site.com/path1/2020/11-12 | 2020 | 11-12 |
| /www.site.com/path1/2020/07-08 | 2020 | 07-08 |
| /www.site.com/path1/resort/ | null | null |

the following regex for the year worked:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(url,'([0-9]{4})') >> result: 2020, null etc.
```

but the regex for the month didnt extract only the months:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(url,'((?:[0-9]{4}/)[0-9]+.?[0-9]*/)') >> result: 2020/11-12/,2021/02/, null etc.
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```golang
(?:^|/)((?:19|20)[0-9]{2})/((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]))?)(?:/|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YN4Did/2).

If you need to capture only once per a match, replace the capturing group with non-capturing, or remove the extra pattern:

```golang
REGEXP_EXTRACT(col_url, '(?:^|/)((?:19|20)[0-9]{2})(?:/|$)') as Year
REGEXP_EXTRACT(col_url, '(?:^|/)((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]))?)(?:/|$)') as Month
```

*Details*:

- `(?:^|/)`  - string start or `/`
- `((?:19|20)[0-9]{2})` - Group 1: a year, `19` or `20` followed with any two digits
- `/` - a `/` char
- `((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]))?)` - Group 2 (month): an optional `0` and then `1` to `9`, or `1` and then `0` to `2` (`00`-`12`), and then an optional occurrence of `-` and the same month pattern
- `(?:/|$)` - `/` or end of string.